# Large lagging on mouse movement with SketchUp Dae model

Tags: three.js, webgl, sketchup

I’ve designed a 3D model in SketchUp and I didn’t use any texture. I’m faced with an issue related with lagging on mouse move and rotate process. When I exported the model by Dae format and imported to the three js online editor ([three js online editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XwhK.jpg)) mouse movement is being very slow. I think it occurs fps drop. I couldn’t understand what’s problem with my model that I designed. I need your suggestions and ideas how to resolve this issue. Thanks for your support. I’ve uploaded 3D model’s image. Please take a look.

Object Count: 98.349, Vertices: 2,107.656, Triangles: 702.552

[image: SketchUp Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Object Count: 98.349,

The object count results in an equal number draw calls. Such a high value will degrade the performance no matter how complex the respective geometry eventually is.

I suggest you redesign the model and ensure to merge individual objects as much as possible. Also try to lower the number of vertices and faces.

Keep in mind that `three.js` does not automatically merge or batch render items. So it's your responsibility to optimize assets for rendering. It's best to do this right when designing the model. Or in code via methods like [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=buffergeo#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries) or via instanced rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I deleted the some objects from the scene the object count is highly decreased. I'm going to try merge objects as possible. Which one is the represent polygon count in threejs scene ? vertices or triangles ?

Comment: Better to focus on triangles.